# Listas anidadas con Flask y Jinja

Tags: python, html5, flask

Estoy intentando crear un menú para una aplicación web hecha con Flask.

Para crear el menú desde Python le paso una lista, con los elementos del mismo, a cada vista que lleva incorporado el menú. Dentro de un Blueprint, la primera vista que lleva este menú tiene el siguiente código, donde el decorador @filter_menu simplemente filtra la lista según los permisos que tenga asignado el usuario *logeado*, para que no le muestre algunas opciones reservadas al admin.

```
Python
@bp.route('/home', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@filter_menu
def home(menu):
    return render_template('admin/home.html', menu=menu)
```

El menú que se pasa por parámetro y que luego es pasado a la función `render_template(menu)` es el siguiente diccionario:

```
Python
menu = {
            'Inicio': [],
            'Usuarios': [],
            'Trabajadores': ['Estado','Contratos', 'Informes'],
        }
```

Este diccionario lo recibe una plantilla llamada side_menu.html con el siguiente código:

```
Jinja
<nav class="sidemenu">
    <ul>
        {% for key in menu %}
            <li>
                <div>{{ key }}</div>
                {% if menu.key|length != 0 %}
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in key.children  %}
                        <li><div>{{ item }}</div></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Lo que creo que hace este código (aunque no es así) es crear la siguiente estructura:

```
<nav>
    <ul>

        <li><div>Inicio</div></li>


        <li><div>Usuarios</div></li>


        <li><div>Trabajadores</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div>Estado</div></li>

                    <li><div>Contratos</div></li>

                    <li><div>Informes</div></li>

                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Sin embargo, cuando lo incorporo mediante un include en la página base y la página se renderiza, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
<nav>
    <ul>

        <li><div>Inicio</div></li>


        <li><div>Usuarios</div></li>


        <li><div>Trabajadores</div></li>

                <ul>

                    <li><div>Estado</div></li>

                    <li><div>Contratos</div></li>

                    <li><div>Informes</div></li>

                </ul>


    </ul>
</nav>
```

El último `<li>`, el de Trabajadores, debería estar incluyendo la lista, pero no lo hace. ¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué y cómo puede conseguir el resultado pretendido?

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un par de cosas.

**Primera**. Tu sintaxis jinja es incorrecta. Por ejemplo aquí:

```
{% for key in menu %}
       ...
                {% if menu.key|length != 0 %}
```

La variable `key` va tomando como valores las claves del diccionario. Por ejemplo, en la primera iteración tomaría el valor "Inicio". Sin embargo `menu.key` no se traduce *magicamente* en `menu.Inicio`, que es lo que querrías, sino que intenta acceder a una clave llamada "key". Es decir, en tu estructura de datos Python estaría intentando ir a `menu["key"]`, en vez de `menu[key]` como tú querrías. Ya que esa clave no existe, el `if` no se cumple y no entra por él nunca.

**Segundo** Precisamente como consecuencia de lo anterior, ya que nunca entra por ese `if` no entiendo cómo es que te sale el sub-menú para el caso "Trabajadores". De hecho no sale eso. Ejecutando tu código a mi me sale:

```
<nav class="sidemenu">
    <ul>

            <li>
                <div>Inicio</div>

            </li>

            <li>
                <div>Usuarios</div>

            </li>

            <li>
                <div>Trabajadores</div>

            </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

que es consistente con la explicación dado en el párrafo primero.

## Solución

Para acceder a la clave `key` del menú, como se ha dicho `menu.key` no sirve. Deberías usar `menu.get(key)`. Por otro lado, esa sintaxis ya te devuelve el contenido de ese elemento del diccionario, que en tu caso es una lista. Por tanto no necesitas usar `.children` en ningún punto. Así que también debes sustituir `menu.key.children` por simplemente `menu.key()`. Con esto ya sale como querrías.

También puedes usar en jinja la siguiente sintaxis, más pythónica que te evita el uso de `get()` y queda más limpia y legible:

```
<nav class="sidemenu">
    <ul>
        {% for key, submenu in menu.items() %}
            <li>
                <div>{{ key }}</div>
                {% if submenu | length != 0 %}
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in submenu  %}
                        <li><div>{{ item }}</div></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```